# How to load a textfile on a string

Tags: jquery

I am not very good at jquery and i am having some trouble to load a text file and show it on a string.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#typed").typed({
            strings: ["Hello World"], //i want to load a text file and show it here.
            typeSpeed: 50,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); },
            resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
        });

        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $("#typed").typed('reset');
        });
    });

    function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

    function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
</script>
```

This is what i try:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.get('file.txt', function(data) {
            alert(data) //just to se that it has loaded.
        });
        $("#typed").typed({
            strings:  function(){ data(); }, //the alert shows the text in the file but here it does not show the text.
            typeSpeed: 50,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); },
            resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
        });

        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $("#typed").typed('reset');
        });
    });

    function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

    function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
</script>
```

As you can see this maybe does not make sense.
Sorry for any english mistakes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.get` is asynchronous. This means that the `typed()` object is instanciated before the `data` is retrieved. With any AJAX request, any code that depends on its result must be placed in the callback. Try this:

```
$.get('file.txt', function(data) {
    alert(data) //just to se that it has loaded.
    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: data,
        typeSpeed: 50,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function() { 
            foo(); 
        },
        resetCallback: function() { 
            newTyped(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that from the [Typed documentation](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) that the `strings` property needs to be an array of strings, not HTML as your current AJAX request is returning.

Comment: thank you, it worked. Now i see why it did not work. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.